# How to generate PDF from HTML with input tags and value filled inside input tags as it is inside?

Tags: pdf-generation, tcpdf, fpdf, jspdf

i have a form with values entered by user. I am showing to the user, form & values entered to the form inside that respective input tags. Now this scenario is on web but i also have to let user download each form with its input as PDF report

That pdf report will have form & values filled inside the form as it is as its shown to him on web.

I tried FPDF & jsPDF but came across alot of problems incorporating CSS inside the PDF. Other than these two is there any solution which help me achieve my objectives? Need help. thank in advance for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php

Answer (score 0):

Try using mPDF. Here's the link to their [Stylesheets & CSS](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=254) manual.